# Simple Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Question: Class consists of $7$ men and $5$ women. Find number of committees of five that can be selected from the class if the committee is to consists of at least one man and at least one woman.

My Solution: $\dbinom{7}{1}\cdot \dbinom{5}{4} + \dbinom{7}{2}\cdot \dbinom{5}{3} + \dbinom{7}{3}\cdot \dbinom{5}{2} + \dbinom{7}{4}\cdot \dbinom{5}{1} = 770$(?)

Solution: $\dbinom{12}{5} - \dbinom{7}{5} - \dbinom{5}{5} = 5522$

Obviously my process was wrong. Would someone please help me understand why I was wrong?
Or how my method of getting the answer is wrong.

Comment: the way "solution" was counted was based on: finding the total number of committees without any restrictions and then subtracting the "bad" committees, where "bad" means the committees which either don't have any men or don't have any women. PS: I'm not saying your approach is incorrect.

Comment: What this means is that the solution was correct, both mine and the book's, but the book's solution did not equal 770, which it should have, as one commented. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer is correct, which also matches the solution. You calculated the solution wrong I believe. Look at this:

$$\dbinom{12}{5}-\dbinom{7}{5}-\dbinom{5}{5} = 770$$

Comment: Wow. Sorry I'm looking at this book and the solution according to it is this (12C5)−(7C5)−(5C5) but equaling to 5522.. Thank you